# Fail to pass raw pointer to ioctl in Rust 1.56.1 using Nix 0.23.1

Tags: linux, rust, system-calls

I'm trying to pass a file descriptor to the ioctl system call.
I'm trying to link a loop device to a file so I can then set an offset so I can mount it correctly.

I have the following code snippet:

```
use std::fs::{File, OpenOptions};

use std::os::unix::io::{AsRawFd, RawFd};
use nix::{ioctl_none, ioctl_write_ptr};
use crate::consts::consts::{MAGIC_NUMBER_SIZE, SIGNATURE_SIZE};

const LOOP_MAGIC_BIT: u8 = 0x4C;
const LOOP_SET_FD: u32 = 0x4C00;
const LOOP_SET_STATUS64: u32 = 0x4C04;
const LOOP_CTL_GET_FREE: u32 = 0x4C82;

ioctl_none!(loopback_read_free_device, LOOP_MAGIC_BIT, LOOP_CTL_GET_FREE);
ioctl_write_ptr!(loopback_set_device_fd, LOOP_MAGIC_BIT, LOOP_SET_FD, RawFd);
ioctl_write_ptr!(loopback_set_device_info, LOOP_MAGIC_BIT, LOOP_SET_STATUS64, LoopbackInfo);

pub struct Loopback {}

pub struct LoopbackInfo {
    pub io_offset: u64
}

impl Loopback {
    pub fn mount_loopback_device(file_path: &str) -> String {
        // Open the loopback control device
        let loopback_control = File::open("/dev/loop-control");

        // Check if is open correctly
        match loopback_control {
            Ok(control_fd) => {
                unsafe {
                    // Format the device path
                    let result = format!("/dev/loop{}", loopback_read_free_device(control_fd.as_raw_fd()).unwrap());

                    // Open the device and the container
                    let container_file = OpenOptions::new().read(true).write(false).open(file_path);
                    let device_file = OpenOptions::new().read(true).write(true).open(result.clone());

                    // Check if is open correctly both files
                    if container_file.is_err() {
                        panic!("[Error]: Failed to open the application file");
                    }

                    if device_file.is_err() {
                        panic!("[Error]: Failed to open the device file");
                    }

                    // Get the raw pointer from the files
                    let raw_device_fd = device_file.unwrap().as_raw_fd();
                    let raw_container_fd = container_file.unwrap().as_raw_fd();

                    // Match file and device
                    match loopback_set_device_fd(raw_device_fd, raw_container_fd as *const RawFd) {
                        Ok(_) => {
                            // Prepare new offset
                            let loop_info = LoopbackInfo {
                                io_offset : (MAGIC_NUMBER_SIZE + SIGNATURE_SIZE) as u64 // Magic Number + Signature Offset
                            };

                            // Set the device information
                            loopback_set_device_info(raw_device_fd, &loop_info as *const LoopbackInfo).unwrap();

                            // Return the path of the prepared device
                            return result.clone();
                        }
                        Err(code) => panic!("[Error]: Failed to associate the file with the device, error code: {}", code)
                    }
                }
            }
            Err(_) => panic!("[Error]: It is impossible to get control over the loopback device")
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to execute these lines, I get the following panic:

> [Error]: Failed to associate the file with the device, error code: EBADF: Bad file number

Comment: Try with `ioctl_write_int!` instead of `ioctl_write_ptr!` for the `LOOP_SET_FD`.

Comment: I tried it at the time, got the same result.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it is a bug in the rust nix library, I will try to report it shortly.  I changed ioctl_write_ptr to ioctl_write_ptr_bad and it worked as it should.